# Why $\frac{1}{f\left(D^{2}\right)} \sin a x=\frac{\sin a x}{f\left(-a^{2}\right)}$ gives the particular solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Recently the topic of second order differential equations and their particular solutions is thought in our college , and they done some messy calculation and arrived at some complex formulas to Solve for particular solutions (they refer it as particular integral) , here is a example of one of those

$\frac{1}{f\left(D^{2}\right)} \sin a x=\frac{\sin a x}{f\left(-a^{2}\right)}$

But  I am familiar with the method which uses trial solutions to find particular solution

So it is very hard to comprehend that how the term ($\frac{1}{f\left(D^{2}\right)} \sin a x$) can refer to particular solution of a differential equation with sinusoidal forcing term

Someone plese help me to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $D:=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$

$D(\sin ax)=a\cos ax, D^2(\sin ax)=(-a^2)\sin ax$

It serves for notational convenience. Given an ODE with constant coefficients, $f(D)y=p(x)$ then a particular solution is denoted by $y_p=\frac 1{f(D)}p(x).$ Think of it as $\overbrace{\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm dx}(x)=g(x)}^{Df(x)=g(x)}\implies \overbrace{f(x)=\int g(t)\,dt}^{f(x)=\frac 1{D} g(x)}.
$

Note that $D^{2r}(\sin ax)=(-a^2)^r\sin ax, r\ge 1$.

Suppose that the given ODE is:

$(D^{2r}+a_{2r-2}D^{2r-2}+...+a_2D^2)y=\sin ax\implies y=\frac 1{f(D^2)}\sin ax,\tag 1$
where  $f(D^2):=D^{2r}+a_{2r-2}D^{2r-2}+...+a_2D^2$.

Note that: $(D^{2r}+a_{2r-2}D^{2r-2}+...+a_2D^2)\sin ax=f(D^2)\sin ax=f(-a^2)\sin ax\tag 2$

Use $(2)$ in $(1)$ to get: $y=\frac 1{f(-a^2)}\sin ax,$ provided that $f(-a^2)\ne 0$.

Comment: Okay thanks , but I have a doubt You defined $f(D^2):=D^{2r}+a_{2r-2}D^{2r-2}+...+a_2D^2$ where order of differentiation always a multiple of 2 , means if my equation have the form $a D^{2}+b D+c y=\sin(gx)$ (where a,b,c,g are constants ) this formula will not work ??

Comment: @GaneshKhadanga: It will but with small modification.  Actually the proof in this answer will work whenever $f$ has only even powers of $D$. For the general case: refer accepted answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350045/arriving-at-a-particular-solution-of-the-ode-y-2y-2y-sin-x.

Comment: Okay , but still I have lots of confusion about derivation of other similar formulas , so can you please suggest me any book or material to study these in detail

Comment: @GaneshKhadanga: If you look up "linear differential operators for solving ODEs" online, you should get lot of material to study this method more.

Comment: One more thing I want to ask ,  1/f(D) refer to integration .... , But in this formula $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cdot e^{a x} \cdot \phi(x)=e^{a x} \cdot \frac{1}{f(D+a)} \cdot \phi(x)$ what does $\frac{1}{f(D+a)}$ mean

Comment: @GaneshKhadanga: $f(D+a)$ means that in the expression for $f(x)$, replace $x$ by $D+a$. An example: $(D^2-4D+9)y=e^{2x}\sin 2x$ has a particular solution given by $e^{2x}\frac 1{(D+2)^2-4(D+2)+9} \sin 2x=e^{2x}\frac 1{D^2+5}\sin 2x=e^{2x}\frac 1{-4+5}\sin 2x=e^{2x}\sin 2x$. Also note that $1/f(D)$ is not really integration but is 'similar' to integration.